# How to take in both input split by space(s) and by line(s)

Tags: python, input

for example I have this 2 inputs:

```
2 5 2
```

and:

```
2
5
2
```

How do I take all of them using the same code?

Comment: @mozway That won't work for the second form, you have to call `input()` 3 times.

Comment: Well, `input` does one line at a time.  You could do `sys.stdin.read().split()`.

Comment: can it check for 2 type of inputs?

Comment: If you need to, sure.  You can split the first line you get and count how many words there were.

Comment: @mozway -- Because, as I said, `input()` only returns one line at a time.

Comment: @TimRoberts `sys.stdin.read()` will wait for EOF.

Comment: Reading between the lines, most questions like this derive from school assignments where the input is being fed from a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read lines of input and split them until you get 3 total values.

```
inputs = []
while len(inputs) < 3:
    values = input().split()
    inputs.extend(values)

print(inputs) # this will print [2, 5, 2]
```

Comment: He just said he wants to take them all in using the same code. Why can't that code use `input()` in a loop like this?

Comment: Yes I realized I used `input` in my comment for a quick demo but I actually had a string input in mind. Indeed if this is dynamic user input, you need to call `input` several times. I guess OP should clarify what is really needed.

Comment: I interpreted it as input from the terminal, not a parameter to the function.

Comment: This will work if input is redirected to a file, too.